# JSP Printing hostname

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I have below code in my JSP for non prod environments to display host name

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.serverName ne 'demo.com' and pageContext.request.serverName ne 'sdemo.com'}">
    <%
        InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String node = ia.getHostName();
        out.println("<!-- hostname  " + node+  " -->");
    %>
    <div id="notProd"><spring:message code="nonproduction.environment.message" /> <c:out value="${node}" />
</c:if>
```

The above code displays the hostname correctly in hidden message when I do view source but its not displaying the `node` value on the page, how do I tweak the `c:out` to display `node` value on JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.serverName ne 'demo.com' and pageContext.request.serverName ne 'sdemo.com'}">
    <%
        InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String node = ia.getHostName();
        out.println("<!-- hostname  " + node+  " -->");
        pageContext.setAttribute("node", node);
    %>
    <div id="notProd"><spring:message code="nonproduction.environment.message" />
 <c:out value="${node}" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: I tried adding `if(node.endsWith('1')) node = "Master"; else node = "Slave";` but its throwing some error, how do i incorporate this change?